# Extracting Data from String Cell; Type mismatch for integer

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following code to determine cable size and type from one cell then use that information to display a number into another cell:

```
Dim rowNum3 As Integer, Num_of_string As Integer, cablesize1 As String, firstNum As Integer

Num_of_string = 4

For rowNum3 = 4 To 50
    cablesize1 = Cells(rowNum3, 9).Value
    firstNum = Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)
    
    If cablesize1 Like "*AL*" = True Then
        If cablesize1 Like "*1/0*" = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(32, 7).Value
        ElseIf cablesize1 Like "*2/0*" = True Or cablesize1 Like "*3/0*" = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(33, 7).Value
        ElseIf cablesize1 Like "*4/0*" = True Or cablesize1 Like "*250*" = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(34, 7).Value
        ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(35, 4).Value, Cells(35, 5).Value)) = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(35, 7).Value
        ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(36, 4).Value, Cells(36, 5).Value)) = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(36, 7).Value
        ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(37, 4).Value, Cells(37, 5).Value)) = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(37, 7).Value
        ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(38, 4).Value, Cells(38, 5).Value)) = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(38, 7).Value
        End If
    ElseIf cablesize1 Like "*AL*" = False Then
        If cablesize1 Like "*2 *" = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(32, 6).Value
        ElseIf cablesize1 Like "*1 *" = True Or cablesize1 Like "*1/0*" = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(33, 6).Value
        ElseIf cablesize1 Like "*2/0*" = True Or cablesize1 Like "*3/0*" = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(34, 6).Value
        ElseIf cablesize1 Like "* 350 *" = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(35, 6).Value
        ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(36, 2).Value, Cells(36, 3).Value)) = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(36, 6).Value
        ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(37, 2).Value, Cells(37, 3).Value)) = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(37, 6).Value
        ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(38, 2).Value, Cells(38, 3).Value)) = True Then
            Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = Worksheets("Tables").Cells(38, 6).Value
        End If
    Else
        Cells(rowNum3, 10).Value = "NA"
    End If
Next rowNum3
```

I'm getting an error here:

`ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(35, 4).Value, Cells(35, 5).Value)) = True Then`

There is a type mismatch on `Cint` I tried different ways to convert the string to a number but it wont work

Sample cell where I get the string from (I use 'AL' at the end to determine whether it is copper or aluminum) the number in the beginning is what i try to convert

[image]

table where I get info from

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's not clear why you're using `Intersect`. `Range(Cells(38, 2).Value, Cells(38, 3).Value)` - what is in those cells?

Comment: Those cells are the aluminum min/max in the table above. 
I trying to figure out if the number I'm converting is within that range. If that doesn't work I'd love any suggestion for checking if a value is in a range

edit: I got application.intersect online, idk if its the right way to go about it

Comment: `Intersect` is used for `Range` objects, not numbers. Use `>` and `<`.

Comment: I see, thank you, so CInt would work in this case as well? 
to convert the beginning of the string to an integer?

Comment: Better to use `CLng` and `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: I would also be averse to using `= True` to test the truth of a statement. It is redundant and reduces the readability of your code.

Comment: Thank you BigBen and Super Symmetry for the input, I will implement both of your comments

Comment: There is no way to match the code to the sample data without knowing the column and row numbers for the table.  It appears that every lookup has the possibility of returning `1/0`.  `1/0` is not a number and can not be converted to a number.

Comment: @TinMan I think that's why he's using `Left` function. I didn't study the code in detail but when I saw the function,  I just assumed that's what it was doing.

Comment: @TinMan Thats why I added ElseIf 's  if the code doesn't detect any `'number'/0` anywhere it'll start testing the numbers after I converted them using `Left`

Comment: I did not follow your whole code logic, but I would replace: `ElseIf Application.Intersect(CInt(Left(cablesize1, Num_of_string)), Range(Cells(35, 4).Value, Cells(35, 5).Value)) = True Then` with `ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Cells(rowNum3, 9).Value, Range(Cells(35, 4).Value, Cells(35, 5).Value)) is nothing Then` and only after that I would check the `Left...` condition...

Comment: @FaneDuru thank you but i got it working with the previous comments

Comment: So, could you intersect an integer obtained from a string with other ranges? I am afraid that your code never reaches this line, but if your code works, good for you!